# Backbone Testing - Trigger "change" event on 'select' element

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, events, backbone.js

In the `Backbone` app I am working on, namely the tests for it, I have a view that has it's event hash set to trigger a function when a `change` event occurs on a `select` element in the `DOM`.

When I listen for the call on the `spy` I created for that function, this is never called.

How can I manually trigger the `change` event for the `option` element in the `select` element?

I have the following code to create the event:

```
it('change on element "select" calls "clickedElement"', function () {

        // Create a new 'change' event
        var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent("change", true, true);

        // Dispatch it.
        this._view.el.querySelector('option[selected]').dispatchEvent(event);

        expect(this.clickedElementSpy).has.been.called;

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution possible :

```js
var log = function( val ){   document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend' ,'<div>' + val + '</div>');
 };


var sel = document.getElementsByTagName('select')[0];


sel.onchange = function(){
  log('changed')
};


var event = new Event('change');

// Dispatch it.
sel.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<select>
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
</select>
```

So in your use case :

```
it('change on element "select" calls "clickedElement"', function () {

    // Create a new 'change' event
         //var event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
         //event.initEvent("change", true, true);

    var event = new Event('change');


    // Dispatch it.
         //this._view.el.querySelector('option[selected]').dispatchEvent(event);

    this._view.el.querySelector('select').dispatchEvent(event);

    expect(this.clickedElementSpy).has.been.called;

});
```

Comment: By setting `sel.onchange` to a function how are you checking that the function in my view is actually being called?

Comment: You ask : How can I ***manually trigger the change event*** for the option element in the select element? , the `sel.onchange` function is there only for logging purpose, it is out of scope but answser to : I have a view that has it's ***event hash set to trigger a function*** when a change event occurs on a select element in the DOM